# getoffer is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have factory declared Malls, but I don't know why I get the error `get offer is not a function!`

```
    .controller('confirmCtrl', function($scope,Malls,$stateParams,$log) {
        $scope.offers = Malls.getoffer($stateParams.offersId);

        console.log($scope.offers,"test");      
    })

    var offers=[{
        id:0,
        message:'Are you  sure want to buy  this coupon?'
    }, {
        id:1,
        message:'Are you  sure want to buy  this coupon?'  
    }];

    return {
        all:function(){
            return offers;
        },
        getoffer: function(offersId) {
            return _.find(offers, function(offers) {
                return offers.id == offersId;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The value for `Malls` in the constructor for your controller is handled by angular's dependency injection. Therefore angular must be informed of the existence of `Malls` to be able to inject it into your controller.

It appears based upon the code that you have defined above that `Malls` is just a global function and based upon that assumption you can do the following:

```
<Your Module>.service('Malls', Malls);
```

The first parameter `'Malls'` will need to match the parameter in your controller's constructor.

The second parameter is the function/constructor to your service.

**Update**

```
// declare your service...
function Malls(){
  var offers = [{
      id:0,
      message:'Are you  sure want to buy  this coupon?'
    }, {
      id:1,
      message:'Are you  sure want to buy  this coupon?'  
    }];
  this.all = function(){
    return offers;
  };
  this.getOffer = function(id){
    var offer;
    // logic to determine offer
    return offer;
  };
}

// add your service to your angular module...
<Your Module>.service('Malls', Malls);
```

Comment: i write that where in service ? i have this angular.module('starter.services',[])

Comment: I added a more detailed example to my answer to explain the creation of a service and adding it to your angular module.